# How should I name my columns in my SQL database?

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

When I create a Database and I need a column with a name like "to settings", what is the best practice? Normally, I write variable in camel-case, but I'm not sure.

`to_settings` or `toSettings`

Comment: It's your system, do as you please. Just be consistent.

Comment: Rows in a database table have no name. Do you mean columns? As to naming, I would never rely on upper / lower case. There are tools that format your queries and are oblivious to what a name actually means. If you are happy with names like `customitemdescription` and `CUSTOMITEMDESCRIPTION`, fine. I'd rather go with `custom_item_description` and `CUSTOM_ITEM_DESCRIPTION` for readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer lower case always, like

`to_settings`

Check this blog
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/10/26/the-power-of-a-good-sql-naming-convention/

Comment: Nice link, but you might want to include some of the core ideas here. If that link ever breaks the whole answer will be less useful. Beyond that: there wasn't a need to delete your answer on that other question. After your chances I would happily have reversed my vote!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "right" or "wrong" way to name things in your own database. What is important, though, is that you stay consistent.

So if you have one field called `to_settings`, you should continue to use all lowercase, underscored names as opposed to later switching to `somethingLikeThis`.

Here is an interesting blog post which highlights that **underscores** are typically common in database applications, but there is a growing desire to begin formalizing and using camelCase or PascalCase as well.
https://sqltechblog.com/2016/10/10/making-the-case-for-camelcase-naming/

Answer (score 1):

As @JNevill said it's your system so do as you want, but if it's your first time developing a database this [link](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/10/26/the-power-of-a-good-sql-naming-convention/) could help you a bit on developing a good database.

A good naming convention and formatting will help all the developers to understand better the DB and table connections.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as **SQL** convert all identifiers to a standard case (UPPER CASE in the **SQL standard**, but lower case EG **PostgreSQL**), most people prefer the former one.

However when using identifier quotation (usually with double quotes, but in **MySQL**/**MariaDB** with backticks) the case is not changed.